# AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'gui_done'

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a chat app with a socet and when I run my gui loop, variables from it do not work in other functions.

Here is my code:

```py
class App():

    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user=user
        self.clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.clientSocket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 9090))
        guit=threading.Thread(target=self.gui)
        lstn=threading.Thread(target=self.listen)
        
        guit.start()
        lstn.start()
        
    def gui(self):  
        self.root=Tk()
        self.username=Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text=self.user)
        self.username.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.hist=ScrolledText(self.root, width=40, height=25 , font=("Arial",15))
        self.hist.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.hist.grid(column=0,row=1, columnspan=2)
        self.msg=Entry(self.root, font=("Arial",15))
        self.msg.grid(row=2,column=0)
        btnSend=Button(self.root, font=("Arial",15), text="Send", command=self.send)
        btnSend.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.gui_done=True
        self.root.bind("<Return>", self.send)
        self.root.mainloop()
        
    
    def addMessage(self, message):
        self.hist.configure(state=NORMAL)
        self.hist.insert(END, f'{message}\n')
        self.hist.configure(state=DISABLED)
        
    
    def send(self,e=None):
        self.clientSocket.send(f'[{self.user}]{self.msg.get()}'.encode())
        print(self.msg.get())
        self.msg.delete(0,END)
    
    def listen(self):
        self.clientSocket.send(f'[SERVER]{self.user} has joined'.encode())
        while 1:
            msgFromServer=self.clientSocket.recv(1024)
            print(msgFromServer)
            if self.gui_done:
                self.addMessage(msgFromServer.decode())
```

I run the `App` class with a username but always get this error:

```py
Exception in thread Thread-2 (listen):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib\\threading.py", line 1016, in \_bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib\\threading.py", line 953, in run
self.\_target(\*self.\_args, \*\*self.\_kwargs)
File "C:\\code\\https\\qttest\\client1.py", line 52, in listen
if self.gui_done:
AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'gui_done'
```

Comment: Well, clearly, `gui()` hasn't been run before you try to look up that attribute

Comment: That is because gui_done isn't defined until the end of the `gui` method and so when you call `App.listen` the self.gui_done attribute doesn't exist... which should be rather obvious since you run the mainloop before you create the gui_done attribute

Comment: i tried that but it still doesnt work

Comment: You need to initialize `self.gui_done` before starting the two threaded tasks.  Actually you should not run the GUI task in a child thread, run it in the main thread.

Comment: can you give an examlple please as everytime i try i  get error 'main thread is not main loop'

Answer (score 0):

Since both the `gui()` and `listen()` are started at almost the same time, `self.gui_done` may not be initialized when it is accessed inside `listen()`.

To fix this, simply initialize `self.gui_done` before starting the two threaded tasks:

```py
class App():
    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user
        self.gui_done = False # initialize gui_done before staring the threaded tasks
        ...
```

However, running tkinter GUI in a child thread is not recommended. It is better to run it in main thread instead.  Below is the modified code to run GUI in main thread based on your code:

```py
import socket
import threading
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

class App():

    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user=user
        self.clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.clientSocket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 9090))
        self.gui() # run GUI code in main thread
        lstn=threading.Thread(target=self.listen, daemon=True)
        lstn.start()

    def gui(self):
        self.root=Tk()
        self.username=Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text=self.user)
        self.username.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.hist=ScrolledText(self.root, width=40, height=25 , font=("Arial",15))
        self.hist.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.hist.grid(column=0,row=1, columnspan=2)
        self.msg=Entry(self.root, font=("Arial",15))
        self.msg.grid(row=2,column=0)
        btnSend=Button(self.root, font=("Arial",15), text="Send", command=self.send)
        btnSend.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.root.bind("<Return>", self.send)
        #self.root.mainloop() # not recommend to run mainloop() here

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def addMessage(self, message):
        self.hist.configure(state=NORMAL)
        self.hist.insert(END, f'{message}\n')
        self.hist.configure(state=DISABLED)

    def send(self,e=None):
        self.clientSocket.send(f'[{self.user}]{self.msg.get()}'.encode())
        print(self.msg.get())
        self.msg.delete(0,END)

    def listen(self):
        self.clientSocket.send(f'[SERVER]{self.user} has joined'.encode())
        while 1:
            msgFromServer=self.clientSocket.recv(1024)
            print(msgFromServer)
            # not recommend to update tkinter widget in a child thread directly
            #self.addMessage(msgFromServer.decode())
            # let the mainloop() to update the widget a bit later (one millisecond)
            self.root.after(1, self.addMessage, msgFromServer.decode())

App("Test User").run()
```